# CPU stuck at base clock after BIOS update

Tags: windows-10, cpu, task-manager, clockspeed

After a BIOS update, Task Manager is reporting that my CPU clock speed is always at base clock (2.59GHz), even under stress, but the graph doesn't report this:

[image]

Is this normal? Should I be worried? Is this an issue with my computer or Task Manager, because my computer seems to be working fine.

Comment: The graph shows utilization. Which is not the same as speed. So the graph is fine. If the clock never changes from base-speed it seems that Intel Speedstep is disabled in Bios. It isn't unusual for bios-settings to be changed/messed up after an update. The recommendation is always to do a "reset to factory defaults" in Bios after an update to make sure the bios-settings have sane values. Did you do that?

Comment: I will try, thank you

Comment: This worked for me, much appreciated. Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph shows utilization, which is not the same as clock speed, so the graph itself is fine, but if the clock speed never changes from base speed, it seems that Intel SpeedStep is disabled in BIOS.

It isn't unusual for BIOS settings to be changed/messed up after an update. The general recommendation for any BIOS update is always to do a "reset to factory defaults" or "reset to optimized defaults" in the BIOS after an update to make sure the BIOS settings have sane values.

After that you can further fine tune the BIOS settings with any additional special settings if needed (if you are not aware of any special BIOS settings you probably don't need them).

So try resetting your BIOS settings and see if that fixes the problem.